# Catch JavaScript exceptions from WebView in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, webview

I need to catch errors that occur in `WebView` if `WebView` is present in the screen. That is not to bind to a specific `WebView`.

Comment: `UIWebView`? `WKWebView`? `not to bind to a specific WebView` ??

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you have already tried this solution,You can catch the exception in your JS code and call a native method to log this information. You can inject this native method implementation into JS context of the UIWebview after a receiving below UIWebView delegate callback that JS context for the webView has been created.

```
- (void)webView:(id)webView didCreateJavaScriptContext:(JSContext *)context forFrame:(id)frame {
//this injects the MyNativeLog in your UIWebView JS context and you can call this function in your JS code.
context[@"MyNativeLog"] = ^(NSString *string){
            NSLog(@"%@", string);
        };
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Vadim Denisuk, Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Chandra, I do not need to call the code from JavaScript. I will not have access to the javaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

The following may helps you please check the below link which is already exist

[How can my iPhone Objective-C code get notified of Javascript errors in a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780042/xcode-webview-connection-server-error-handling)

You can hook UIWebView control to hidden WebKit framework and get all exceptions, executed functions and similar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `webView:didClearWindowObject:forFrame:` method of `WebFrameLoadDelegate Protocol`.

Check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView:didClearWindowObject:forFrame:

There you can catch any type of javascript exception that happens to occur. This is not bind to a specific WebView.